# How to hash an address?

Tags: solidity, hash, keccak

I just want to hash the senders' address

```
    function myHash() public returns(string memory){
        return(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender)));
    }
```

but no matter what I do I get the following error

> TypeError: Return argument type bytes32 is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) string memory.

Is there any way to just hash the address?

Answer (score 1):

Your return type (`bytes32`) doesn't match the declared return type (`string`).

Just change your function declaration for :

```
function hashSenderAddress() public view returns (bytes32) {
    return(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender)));
}
```

A hash is not really a string, it's basically a 32 bytes number (for keccak256 at least). Any "string" representation of it are just hexadecimal formatting, but it's still a number being represented.